# Mongodb how to round a calculated value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So i tried using $round on a calculated value but i still cant get it to work. The current value now is:
9.333333333333334, but i would like to have: 9.3.

This is what i tried:

```js
{
     $set: {
        power: { $sum: ["$power", "$attack", "$defence", { $divide: ["$endurance", 3] },  { $round: ["$power", -1] }] }
     }
  }
];
```

But this won't round the output, how do i fix this?

Comment: Use `power: { $round: [{ $sum: ["$power", "$attack", "$defence", { $divide: ["$endurance", 3] }, 1] }] }`

Answer (score 1):

[$round](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) has this syntax:

```
{ $round : [ <number>, <place> ] }
```

- `<number>` can be any valid expression that resolves to a number.
- `<place>` is optional and can be any valid expression that resolves to an
  integer between -20 and 100.

[image]

You code should look like:

```
{ $round : [ "$power", 1 ] }
```